# Comma in "servicing carriers that are committed to participate and willing and able to adjust market share"

Tags: commas

Troubling sentence:

> Name at least two servicing carriers that are committed to participate
>   and willing and able to adjust market share to cover up to 100% of the
>   risk if necessary.

Is it okay to put a comma after *participate*? Coworkers have gone back and forth over this; we can't find any documentation to support either argument in *Gregg's Reference Manual* or *Words Into Type.*

Comment: Use commas or other punctuation when you need to eliminate ambiguity, or else recast the sentence into smaller sentences. There are no hard-and-fast rules about grouping for clarity. It's about style, not grammar.

Comment: I think the sentence can be clarified without commas: "Name at least two servicing carriers that are committed to participate and *that are* willing and able to adjust market share to cover up to 100% of the risk if necessary." I would be inclined to place a comma before "if necessary" though. Best would probably be to break up the sentence, as WS2 suggests.

Comment: @nxx Putting in _your_ comma switches the meaning to "If necessary, name at least two servicing carriers that are committed to participate and that are willing and able to adjust market share to cover up to 100% of the risk."

Comment: I guess it could be read that way, but I just don't see that it would automatically mean that. I think it leads to being read as "...willing and able to adjust market share to cover up to 100% of the risk, if necessary." Overall, it is an unwieldy and overly complicated sentence that just begs to be misunderstood, which adds to the argument for it being split up.

Comment: You ask about punctuation but don't tell us what the intended meaning of the sentence. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence could take more than one comma. There are other matters concerning length and complexity which make it a wearisome sentence to read. I would break it into two and write it as follows:

'Name at least two servicing carriers who are committed to participate. They must be willing and able to adjust market share, covering 100% of the risk, if necessary.'

But I am, without further elaboration, unclear as to its meaning. So I may have got it completely wrong.

Comment: Sounds like orc mischief to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not be correct to put a comma after "participate".  "are committed to participate" and "willing and able to adjust . . ." both refer to the direct object "servicing carriers" and, therefore, should not be separated from it by a comma.  nxx above provided a good solution to make the sentence flow more smoothly.  Adding a comma before "if necessary" adds an effective pause but is optional.